# Moderator election ballot: Different default images for candidates

Tags: bug, election, flair, profile-picture

If a moderator candidate has not customized his/her profile picture, the image shown for that candidate on a user's ballot is different than the image shown in the candidate list and elsewhere on the site.  This might lead voters to believe something is going wrong when casting their ballot or indicating preferences among these candidates.
Examples (all candidates still using default images on the only site with an active election):
[image: Different image shows]
[image: Different image shows]

EDIT: 
This is what I see when I [view my profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/287315/wbt?tab=profile) here:
[image: Meta profile]

Comment: That's a bug with the flair itself, not really related to election. Leaving the elections tag, as it's also affected, but the core bug is the flair, which for some reason takes wrong version of the Identicon.

Comment: This is almost certainly the same bug as I'm getting [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283643/323179). Check your profile settings and check Area 51.

Comment: @Laurel My image on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/138472/wbt) and in my profile settings have the same green image I've been seeing everywhere else since joining, as in the left of the second screenshot.

Comment: I visited your profile and saw [otherwise](http://i.stack.imgur.com/d1uvb.png). From my research on my previously linked question, I know that your IP location (and therefore which server you get) will cause results to vary wildly. Only certain sizes and certain locations.

Comment: @Laurel I've edited in a screenshot of what I see on my profile here.

Comment: Yes, it all depends on location. See https://geopeeker.com/fetch/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fbad7ae5a0df732efd007cb0469b9e568%3Fs%3D328%26d%3Didenticon%26r%3DPG

Comment: There I see the red image for Brazil, and the green one for all others (Virgina, California, Singapore, Ireland, Australia).

Comment: Reproduced, I also got the red image (in the Netherlands) when voting for you in the mod elections.

Comment: Gravatar is currently serving different Identicons based on the size of image you requested in the URL, and possibly other factors. Their system is broken - it has nothing to do with anything we're doing. We're sending them the same hash in both situations.