# Why is my profile image different?

Tags: bug, profile-page, area-51, data-explorer, gravatar

When I first signed up on a Stack Exchange site and got a profile image, it was this one (<s>see my current user card</s> I'm actually not sure what I look like any more):

[image: One]

Later, I got [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/153298/laurel?tab=stats) and SEDE profiles, and my user image there was a different identicon. Because [reasons I already know](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210703/323179). <s>I would have a picture of it, but that's the problem.</s> ... Thanks to [Bing.com's outdated (?) cache](http://cc.bingj.com/cache.aspx?q=laurel+data+explorer+stack+exchange&d=4529151996332757&mkt=en-US&setlang=en-US&w=UNqlbtvtLMgLnuM5XeGYmNuOHzYPxNfl), I have a picture:

[image: 2]

On those two sites, it changed from that purple one to this new one recently: [image: 3]

I don't know when the change happened exactly, but I KNOW I didn't change it (I don't know how to change it, otherwise I would have changed it to my main pink one).

Why did this change? Can I get my other icon back or will I be stuck with this new one?

Also, are the gravatars at Area 51 and SEDE securely generated?

---

After looking in my profile settings, I really confused (I am seeing my wrong avatar in more and more places since I first posted this.):

> [image: Nothing makes sense]

Seriously.......

[image: Mystery goes world wide]

What...?

[image: Twice!]

(I'm using this [site](https://geopeeker.com/), but be warned that they will try to IP block you after a certain number of requests to force you to pay... May look for a better alternative later.)

Comment: Gravatar is based solely on the email you give it. This most likely means that the email address associated with your SEDE/Area51 accounts is different than the one you use for other sites, or that you have a custom email in the other sites. (I think you can't customise it in SEDE/Area51 and it's based only on the OpenID provider you logged in with.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think SO main salts your e-mail hash, while Area 51 doesn't. (but both are gravatar). That's why the two gravatars are different for faceless users on the two sites.

Comment: @AndrasDeak that might be it indeed. I'm not familiar enough with how Gravatar works behind the scenes, and whether SE pass direct email or the hashed value so can't really make a true guess here. We'll probably have to wait for a dev to confirm it either way. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I tried to reproduce my identicon manually based on my e-mail's hash, and if I recall correctly, I ended up with the Area 51 version. Then the SO version is clearly different, so something else must be there:) And I remember to have read something about SO salting gravatar hashes (but this probably wasn't rolled out to Area 51). Right, I [read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204523/unexpectedly-changing-identicon/204540#204540). You even have a comment there:D

Comment: OK, I can't reproduce the Area 51 hash using `md5sum` manually, but [the snippet in this codegolf challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/49566/golf-your-languages-identicon) generates the Area 51 identicon hash for me based on my e-mail address, using only md5 (so I'm probably messing up something when I try to do the same). This sort of proves it: Area 51 identicon hashes are indeed unsalted, and mildly insecure as such.

Comment: @Laurel regarding your edit: your original identicon hash produces the two identicons: [proper with 328 pixels](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/dc4984b955fd2b2105f6c9777b3eb3d4?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1), [purple one with 327 pixels for instance](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/dc4984b955fd2b2105f6c9777b3eb3d4?s=327&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1).

Comment: @AndrasDeak Those appear to be the same image?

Comment: @Laurel maybe for you:D They are [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FaH6V.png) and [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NyM2h.png) for me, respectively. This is why I wrote that it's user(/server?)-specific too. Have you tried the two links in my answer?

Comment: @AndrasDeak Indeed, your two links look the same to me. You're right about different servers, see my edit. Not that the additional information makes any sense beyond that...

Comment: See this MSO question - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332880/why-did-my-avatar-change

Comment: Related: http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1218/hmm-something-funny-with-the-what-do-they-call-it-gravatar/1219#1219 - we're investigating

Comment: @MarcGravell: Here is another instance, in ([tex.se]) chat: [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sg2fQ.png)

Comment: @Werner I'm chasing gravatar

Comment: I shall add that different people are experiencing this issue at different moments. E.g. for me, the change happened only a few hours ago.

Comment: [Another instance](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4144/472), and several hours earlier another user came to chat with this problem.  For people who want to recover their old ones, I was able to find them in the Wayback machine, though not necessarily the most-recent snapshot even though it's older than the change.

Comment: My 4-years old gravatar changed today. Something strange is happening.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev (and Monica Cellio and Victor Stafusa): (Same here. I haven't changed anything, myself.) Seems like SE is having a general problem with its avatars now (starting yesterday, I guess). They replied to an email I sent yesterday asking about it by pointing to this thread and saying it was a Gravatar problem, not an SE problem.

Comment: My "identicon" disappointingly changed as well — [color they say has psychological effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_psychology), and now my identicon seems to evoke "envy" rather than the "excitement" it previously did. Instead of answers typically garnering upvotes it's the opposite, and I'm shell-shocked... I hope they fix this soon; I can't work like this! :p

Comment: @Drew not trying to be snarky, but if you read the question and my answer it's clear that it can't be anything other than a gravatar issue. And it's been going on for more than 10 days now, but it's server-dependent and thus inconsistent. It does seem to be gradually worsening, which fits in [with my hypothesis](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283643/why-is-my-profile-image-different/284078?noredirect=1#comment921065_284037)

Comment: @AndrasDeak: I read the question and your answer. Why do you (apparently) assume I did not? More importantly, I read **Caleb's answer**,* which solved my problem*. All my comment says is that I reported the problem by mail to SE, and the reply indicated that it was a Gravatar problem, not an SE problem. I don't see anything wrong with my saying that or with SE's email response. Just relating more information about this.

Comment: If you changed your name before the change, try cleaning your cache. The identicon is based on your name (and email). The old icon is invalid, the new one is valid. If you want an ever-lasting profile picture, upload your own.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος I have not changed anything. Neither did any of the other people who have this issue.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος what makes you believe that the identicon is based on the name? The Area 51 identicon is solely based on e-mail address, and other sites have e-mail+salt. Of course the salt could be name-based, but I'm pretty sure auto-generated avatars are resistant to name change by design.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Whenever I change my name, the identicon changes (although not immediately visible, you must click 'change picture' to see the changed identicon, and you must cler your cache to see it anywhere else.)

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος wow, I had no idea! Thanks or the input (and I'm really surprised it's so).

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος That's not at all true. It's based on your email, unless you don't have a Gravatar account, then it's based on a salted version of your IP. It changes when you update your profile because it's updating the hash to your new IP address which changed since you last saved your profile.

Comment: I've noticed that new gravatar profile pictures are different: they have reflection symmetry across a vertical line. This wasn't the case in old times, see my current avatar (that is an uploaded image of my first avatar that I like). [My answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283656/313143) shows my "new" avatar and corresponding link from 2016 (that avatar is inconclusive because it matches both the old and new symmetry). But now when I try to switch back to gravatar I get https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/326651e14fcf566dbaea4ebee417cad7?s=328&d=identicon, yuk! Different hash too.

Comment: I guess the symmetry thing is [deemed off-topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387346/why-have-gravatars-become-reflectionally-symmetric-instead-of-rotationally-symme). It's still relevant that hashes seem to have changed again.

Comment: Heads-up: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389123/were-regenerating-all-identicons.

Answer (score 33):

**[Things changed again in 2023](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389123/were-regenerating-all-identicons). Original answer below.**

We noticed the same thing too last night. For at least one user, the gravatars in *chat* were not what they're supposed to be on main, even though the profile pages contained the original gravatars (when loaded by the same chat user), what they should've been.

Looking into the issue, I found myself that my Area 51 gravatars are inconsistent:

[image: area51 screenshot]

Now here's the catch: both icons in the above image point to the same gravatar hash, only with different pixel sizes. It's not strictly reproducible (the user who had the issue in chat *didn't* see the same effect), but for me, here are two gravatar identicons of the same hash with different pixel sizes:

http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/03f2d50ce2e8d713af6058d2aeafab74?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG
[image: 48 pixel version]

http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/03f2d50ce2e8d713af6058d2aeafab74?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG
[image: 128 pixel version]

Note that the only difference in URLs is the pixel size; and note that you may not see the same difference. For the record, the top/small one is the proper identicon I should have on Area 51 (if I'm not mistaken, Area 51 uses an unsalted hash from your e-mail, which is why it's different from main).

The above indicates that this is an issue on the side of gravatar; and the fact that it's user-dependent makes it more fun. I blame caching.

---

Update: after three weeks, both my Area 51 gravatar and my main site gravatar have changed to the "new" one, at every pixel setting, on both my home and work network. I gave up and set my old avatar manually. The bug seems to be spreading steadily, so I'll reiterate my hypothesis [I noted in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283643/why-is-my-profile-image-different/284078?noredirect=1#comment921065_284037):

> Considering that some people are entirely missing their old gravatars, and that for others the old gravatars are only available at specific sizes (those that were used someplace on SE), I have a new hypothesis. What if gravatar messed up/changed their identicon generating algorithm, and the only reason the old ones are around is due to caching? This would explain why only a few sizes are kept as old, and new (hitherto-unused) sizes are generated anew, changing in the process. As I use chat a lot, my avatar is cached there; others who don't, might have their avatar lost with higher probability.

Now that weeks have passed, any caching that kept the old identicons around is gone, and we're left with the new ones. If I'm right, gradually every identicon should change everywhere (unless the user manually sets the old one, of course).

Comment: You might have *another* identicon; check your profile settings (and see my edit). I think this is related to a whole bunch of other posts, like the election one.

Comment: @Laurel [nope](http://i.stack.imgur.com/j8ka5.png). Veeeery odd. I still blame gravatar, and some server-specific mixup on their side. It can't really be anything else if you consider the gravatar-only links and images in my answer. **But hey**: the 328-pixel gravatar of mine is correct; this is in this screenshot. But a 500-pixel one is wrong, and that was the one in chat! [Wtf](http://i.stack.imgur.com/W3HRC.png)

Comment: I did some testing on this tonight, because mine, too, has changed. It seems that _any other size_ than 48x48 causes a different gravatar to be generated. In addition, if you change the rating of your gravatar (from r=PG to one of the other ratings: G, R, or X), the gravatar that's returned is also different than the 48x48 gravatar (but the same as the gravatar generated by specifying a size _other_ than 48x48). So this seems to be wholly on Gravatar's end. So much for "globally recognizable"....

Comment: Okay, but how can I fix this?

Comment: @Wildcard we've contacted gravatar - we're waiting on them

Comment: @Marc I imagine gravatar staff in the last ten days turning every rock in their office to find the *old* identicon algorithm;)

Comment: Relevant: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: Within the past few hours my icon has also changed in a similar way, and I'm seeing a combination of new & old depending on the size it's displayed at. Right now, this is the old one: https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2aac28d67a10b126f4187c4f8dbae839?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG and this is the new one: https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2aac28d67a10b126f4187c4f8dbae839?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG - I think I'll save the old one and manually set it as a permanent icon if I can figure out how…

Comment: @Dave click on your name -> "settings" tab in the profile -> set your avatar manually, uploading the png to SO's imgur account

Answer (score 28):

> Can I get my other icon back or will I be stuck with this new one?

**Maybe.** If you've been using any Stack Exchange site long enough that you've grown attached to your identicon, there's a good chance that it's cached or archived somewhere even if you don't have it yourself.

The tool that worked best for me was Internet Archive's [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/). I used it like this:

1. Navigate to your profile page on your favorite Stack Exchange site. This is the page with the large version of your identicon (even though it's the wrong one). Copy the URL for your profile page. The URL will be of the form: http://*site*.com/users/*youruserid*/*yourusername*?tab=profile
2. Paste that URL into the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/) and cross your fingers that there's a copy. You'll likely get a calendar showing the various dates on which your profile page has been archived. Click one of the dates and see if your old identicon is there. If yes, download the image.
3. Go back to your profile page (the current one) on your favorite Stack Exchange site. Click the identicon to edit it, and upload the image that you just saved. Click the Save button at the bottom of the page when you're done.

Comment: Did your image change in your profile too? I mostly see cases where only non-standard sizes are different. Anyway, since the issue is server-dependent, you have a high chance asking around in chat or friends, some of them will probably see your old avatar with the standard size.

Comment: @AndrasDeak It changed everywhere, at every size.

Comment: I helped somebody do this yesterday and we found that the most recent Wayback Machine entry (from March I think) had the *new* image (WTF?) but an earlier one had the right one.  So don't despair if the latest copy is wrong; go farther back and you might find it.

Comment: This worked for me — but I'm annoyed that I had to go to the effort of fixing what hadn't been broken for 7y 11m.

Comment: Incidentally, my flair is temporarily not showing any avatar at all — neither the old nor the new.  I assume that's because flair is updated every 24 hours or so, but the problem is afflicting that, too.

Comment: I was able to find my old gravatar on Wayback just as you said, went to the Edit Profile page, pasted it in, and no effect.  You should add step 4, click at the bottom of the Edit Profile page to save the changes, either to just that site or the whole network.  After that, it works fine.  Thanks.

Comment: Good call, @RossMillikan -- I added the save button to step 3.

Comment: Easier way - just google your SE username and click Images.

Comment: Can I/you reduplicate your answer on the ELU meta site, please?

Comment: @Araucaria [Done.](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/9511/7225)

Comment: _"If you've... grown attached to your identicon"..._ - "You will adapt." (c) Seven of Nine

Answer (score 24):

There's two different things going on here; on the main site and chat, the problem is an ongoing quirk in gravatar;

I see (this may vary for you):

32-pixels, red - `https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/dc4984b955fd2b2105f6c9777b3eb3d4?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1`:

[image: 32-pixels]

64-pixels, pink - `https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/dc4984b955fd2b2105f6c9777b3eb3d4?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1`:

[image: 64-pixels]

128-pixels, red - `https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/dc4984b955fd2b2105f6c9777b3eb3d4?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1`:

[image: 128-pixels]

This bit is entirely with gravatar. I'll chase them.

In case caching / server-nodes are part of the problem - here's a screen grab of the above *as seen by me right now*: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYTRU.png

---

Secondly, we have area 51; I have manually confirmed that your email details are the same on both sites - they are. But area 51 is outputting a different hash - blue - `https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f0aaa84af6fe9735632f6b4036abd6b0?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG`

[image: blue!].

This appears to be a hashing oddity on area 51 - I will investigate why this is happening; this bit is entirely "us".

Comment: So, [tag:status-planned] then?

Comment: [As I said above](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283643/why-is-my-profile-image-different#comment919362_283643), Area 51 doesn't salt the hash generated from the e-mail.

Comment: I'm going to cut them |:

Comment: No this is not so - my new gravitas in header and profile are the same only cached ones are the old version - and it just happened and it is not just  Area 51

Comment: @TimStone Have you just release something?

Comment: Considering that some people are entirely missing their old gravatars, and that for others the old gravatars are only available at specific sizes (those that were used someplace on SE), I have a new hypothesis. What if gravatar messed up/changed their identicon generating algorithm, and the only reason the old ones are around is due to caching? This would explain why only a few sizes are kept as old, and new (hitherto-unused) sizes are generated anew, changing in the process. As I use chat a lot, my avatar is cached there; others who don't, might have their avatar lost with higher probability.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I'm starting to think it's a Gravatar issue, too. [I looked pretty closely at a case on math.se](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/24916), and the Gravatar URLs for the current and archived versions of the identicon were the same. This strongly suggests to me that Gravatar has altered the algorithm.

Comment: @ureser there's no question that it is a gravatar issue - we know that

Comment: @Marc and let me guess, they totally ignore your requests?

Comment: @ShadowWizard yup; no response  on twitter, and their technical support ["is closed at the moment"](https://en.gravatar.com/support/contact-us/) - seemingly permanently

Comment: Typical. Any way to reproduce their identicon on your side, if it's not trade marked? Looks like Gravatar is dying, slowly but surely, so you'll  just be doing everyone a favor. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I voted that we should go back to unicornify! We're discussing options internally.

Comment: Something strange I noticed: I changed my profile image across all my profiles (to be my original profile image) and my Area 51 *discuss* profile image changed to that, but not my Area 51 profile image (which is still blue now).

Comment: @Laurel something something caching;) When did you change it? I can confirm that right now your profile still points to gravatar.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I changed it yesterday or so (to an uploaded version of my original profile image), since I couldn't stand the top bar being wrong. The thing that surprised me was that my Area 51 Discuss (the "meta" for Area 51) profile uses that image now, but not Area 51.

Comment: @Laurel your problem persists, at this point I'd say it's not caching:P Have you tried setting your Area 51 discussion profile manually? It's two levels of deprecation, actually: main -> Area 51 -> discussion.

Comment: @Laurel Area 51 itself runs on old code base, so without any "new" features, and custom image as avatar is such new feature. However, its discussion zone is a newer site running on the ordinary code base, so having all the features.

Comment: @MarcGravell Has there been any movement from the Gravitar side of things? Or from ours?

Comment: Ping? I find it *very* weird that something as large as gravatar has been lost on the radar for months now.

Comment: @Andras we've contacted them; they know the problem exists. Hopefully it should be fixed. Entirely out of stack's hands, short of changing provider and moving even more cheese