# Identicons changed on profiles (but not posts)

Tags: bug, profile-picture, identicon

It seems that users who have auto-generated identicons as profile images are showing different images on their profile vs on posts. The images shown on posts and in chat are the regular images that have always been, but on profile pages, and reputation leagues, I am seeing different new images. Also seems that the *network* profile shows the original image but *per-site* profiles are showing the new image.

Weirdly, other people don't seem to be seeing this (after asking in chat), but I do even when I'm not logged in and on different network connections. I've only looked at a handful of accounts but all the ones I have checked are showing the same inconsistency.

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Some affected profiles:

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/18306/joojaa
https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/36888/rafael
https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/306/da01
https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/52410/peter-green
https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/3327/user568458

Comment: Please link to (some of) the affected profiles.

Comment: MSE related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283643/why-is-my-profile-image-different

Comment: @rene well, that other one is only for Area51/SEDE difference which makes sense due to using a different hash/salt. This one is more severe.

Comment: hmm.... no repro here, they're all identical for me.

Comment: seems like a gravatar issue with different sizes showing different images... a few people on chat have said they can repro, but most not

Comment: Related: http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1218/hmm-something-funny-with-the-what-do-they-call-it-gravatar/1219#1219 - we're looking, but ultimately this is a gravatar issue, and will probably be fixed by them soon