# Gravatar profile image not showing sometimes

Tags: support, profile-page, profile-picture, gravatar

It seems that with some profiles the Gravatar image is broken. I am not sure if this is an issue with SE or Gravatar, or both, so posting here.

As an example, [this user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1017882/j%E1%B4%80%CA%8Fm%E1%B4%87%E1%B4%87) shows an error on [the image](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8c67873844ebec05668f0fadb87ce6a2?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG), which shows a HTTP 500 on Gravatar.

Profile image on SO:

> [image: profile image on SO]

Image on Gravatar:

> [image: gravatar]

Switching to the MSE profile of the user, the image is working (but has a different hash).

Is this a bug on the SE side? Can anything be done to make Gravatar fix this?

---

**Update 2016-10-04:**

It happened to me again two times today. The last user profile was [this one](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/215b2561d269a9ad5413316bbc020589?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1). Calling the service two or three times fixes the issue.

Comment: Also, is this related to that other Gravatar issue of different Gravatars?

Comment: What other Gravatar issue?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283643/why-is-my-profile-image-different?rq=1

Comment: I get no error on the profile/image you posted

Comment: Indeed. It seems to have been fixed. I will wait a short moment, maybe Oded or someone else fixed this. If not, I can delete it.

Comment: @Cai It's back.

Comment: hmmm... again, not for me :)

Comment: *Calling the service two or three times fixes the issue.* So I guess the cache is set now on their end and it works.

Comment: Yeh, seems it's a Gravatar caching issue.

Comment: Actually, just happened to me when I checked your original Gravatar link.

Comment: [Still happening](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285616/245360)

Comment: Gravatar is broken and they will not fix that. Anyone who still using it, well, should just switch to something that works.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Is it being quietly killed?

Comment: @Stijn you mean by SE? I surely hope so.

Comment: @ShadowWizard No, I meant by the Gravatar owners

Comment: @Stijn oh. Don't think so, more likely they simply don't care.