# Gravatar broke or something

Tags: support, gravatar

My beautiful enzyme avatar is hosted on Gravatar, and it doesn't load on [one of SO's chats](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), and generally SE pages I have open.

[image]

Can someone take a look? I have Chrome version Version 53.0.2785.143 m and it seems to throw a 502 error (Bad Gateway). Others are experiencing this issue as well.

Comment: @Patrick "That solved my problem!" (Seriously though, someone should go change that wording.)

Comment: Watching the game? Quite interesting game...