# User's gravatar's don't load the first time I open their profile

Tags: bug, profile-page, gravatar

When I open a user's profile, I see this:

[image]

Opening it again or clicking refresh fixes this, and shows their gravatar.

[image]

This happens in Google Chrome and Firefox on Ubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Gravatar profile image not showing sometimes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285174/307988)