# My gravatar changed

Tags: support, gravatar

A day or 2 ago, my gravatar changed from a simpler orange symbol that I've had for like 4 years now to a slightly more complex blueish one.

Does anyone know why this would have happened or how to change it back? I liked the old one more.

Comment: Do also note that there have been several similar questions asked here lately which are a result of bugs on Gravatar's end. Not much Stack Exchange can do about that.

Comment: @ale Oh. Honestly, I went over the new questions but I didn't search (my bad). For some reason I didn't expect it to be a common issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not have an email address associated with your account, the gravatar is based off [a salted hash of your IP address](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283643/why-is-my-profile-image-different#comment921613_283643), and will change when your IP address changes, or if you edit your profile (which regenerates the salt).

If you do have an email address associated with your account, it will change if you change your email address.

So if you want the image to stay constant<sup>†</sup>, you either need to have a static IP address and never edit your profile, or associate an email with your account and never change it.

If you find a gravatar you like, the most reliable solution is to download the image then explicitly upload it as your avatar.

Here I found your old one cached:

[image]

---

<sup>†</sup> Disclaimer: There may be other reasons for it to change that I'm not aware of (and things like gravatar bugs, etc.) but suffice it to say that the safest bet is to assume it can change at any time. So if you find one you like, take Beyoncé's advice and put a ring on it!

Comment: I have it linked to my Google account, so I'm not sure if that counts as having an associated email. Maybe I'll see if I can find a hi-res screenshot of the gravatar and upload it. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Carcigenicate See edit. You might be able to find a higher res one somewhere.

Comment: HA! You're awesome. Thank you x2.

Comment: Google's logo today looks more like "gargle".

Comment: Ya, some of their more creative ones require some squinting. Can't blame em for trying to mix it up!