# What was the old identicon generation algorithm?

Tags: discussion, profile-picture, gravatar, identicon

About a year ago, in August, I think, there were some changes made to a hashing algorithm(?) covering up some security hole, or what not, and my avatar was changed as a consequence, and I was wondering whether there is a way for me to get it generated again somehow. I have used various hashing algorithms provided along online identicon generators, but non of them give the same image I have had which makes a lot of guesswork because I don't know whether it is the hash method that is used that is different, or implementation of the generator.

Comment: AFAIK those are generated by Gravatar, an external service. There is nothing SE can do as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284037/158100).

Comment: No, not a year ago. More like [over three years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204540/152859)

Comment: @ShadowWizard, maybe, maybe not. My avatar changed in Aug16 as noted.

Comment: The algorithm was changed to prevent leaks, so I think it's unlikely that Stack Exchange will describe it in detail. You might however ask what would a secure algo be.